# Enviar comillas simple a base de datos sql server con php

Tags: php, sql

Os cuento mi dilema, tengo un scrip el cual guarda lo necesario en base de datos para en futuras ocasiones con esos datos se puedan hacer consultas y demás en el sql desde una aplicación web. El problema es al guardar las cadena de texto que contienen comillas simples ya que no las guarda, y estás son necesarias si o si. En probado varias funciones de php para poder solucionar esto, pero nada. Y no se me ocurre que más hacer ¿Alguna idea?

```
$exc = $_POST["exclusion"];
$ope = $_POST["operador"];
$val = $_POST["valor"];
echo addslashes($val);

echo $sql = "UPDATE dbo.filtros set Exclusion = '$exc', Operador = '$ope', Valor = '$val' WHERE id = 1";
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer un replace (`str_replace()`) cambiando una comilla simple por dos: `$ope = str_replace("'", "''", $ope)`

Comment: Exacto justamente lo probé antes de ver tu comentario y funcionó. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues la solucion al final resultó que era facil, con un `str_replace()` me funcionó.